# New & Overwhelmed

Tags: salat, conversion

Salam! :)

I'm new to Islam, have reverted on the 30th of last month. What I'm having trouble with is feeling overwhelmed and needing to know EVERYTHING as soon as possible. Even though I know that obviously you can't be the perfect Muslim overnight, I feel bad that I don't have everything down as of yet. More so because I have fear of Allah and nervous that He'd send me Hell if I didn't do this or that yet without even knowing what to do yet. :( Any prayers I can to to keep my heart lifted and to soothe my anxiety and stress when trying to learn everything? Also to keep my spirits up when I feel like giving up?

My plan is to first learn obligatory prayers, then any prayers that I can do in-between them and stuff I need to do as a Muslim before doing certain things. I already know about Wudhu and Ghusl. I found this website that has really helped me and I'm using it to write down the whole process of praying down. : http://ifoundislam.net/revert-supports/how-to-pray.html  Is this the correct information?

Thanks so much for reading! May Allah bless you and have a good rest of your day.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] to learn more about this site and how it is supposed to work.

Comment: To your concern: Islam wipes out all the previous (See http://sunnah.com/muslim/1/228), so you could say you are considered as a new born (see https://islamqa.info/en/46505 for more explanation), so any good or bad deed you've done before that doesn't count anymore on the other hand anything you've done since you became a Muslim would do. You ask about clothes, so I need to ask are you female? In that case you are asked to cover yourself if you are male wide clothes would already be fine as there isn't really something called Muslm clothing.

Comment: I forgot to give the advice that of course you are free to split your question :) and I'd like to point at this post which also might be helpful for your case http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32644/going-from-never-prayed-in-my-life-to-my-first-prayer also if you search by tag for example [tag:salat] you may find a lot of helpful answers or questions and note that some are linked on this page according the chosen tags!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I deal with the difficulties I am facing regarding daily prayers?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33566/how-should-i-deal-with-the-difficulties-i-am-facing-regarding-daily-prayers)

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin this is the original post, the duplicate is the one you just edited!

Comment: @Medi1Saif I am writing an answer to the one I edited. Lets close this one and keep the other one. OK?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's two questions both of which are off-topic on this site. 1. Asking for dua recommendation (it's currently of topic). 2. Asking as to go through a url and making comments on it's content (questions on this site are supposed to be self-contained and on-topic). For the first question you could probably try resorting to [chat].