# How should I deal with the difficulties I am facing regarding daily prayers?

Tags: salat, practical-islam

Salam!

So I am new to Islam. I took Shahada on the 30th last month. I have a question regarding prayers, mainly the daily prayers. Can I start off with learning that and then branch out into other prayers? I can do in-between them like how I learned yesterday, I learned you gotta do Wudhu, etc and recite certain things and do certain things before going to bed. I haven't yet completely learned how to do each prayer, I'm still trying to write everything down! Will Allah punish me for not doing them yet as I don't know them all? Will I have to make up prayers (even though I haven't even counted how many days I may have missed it) or is there a prayer I can do to repent and ask for forgiveness?

I'm sorry, I'm still quite new and really fear Allah and 100% believe in the hereafter. I just don't want to die one day unexpected and then be punished for something that I didn't know how to do yet.

Thank you for reading, peace be upon you! :)

Comment: Salam. You should really try to edit your original post/question for revisions.

Answer (score 3):

> So I am new to Islam. I took Shahada on the 30th last month. I have a question regarding prayers, mainly the daily prayers. **Can I start off
>   with learning that and then branch out into other prayers?**

Yes, of course. You don't have to burden yourself with more than what you can bear. Allah says in the Qur'an (what means), “Allah does not burden a soul beyond that it can bear… (Qur’an, 2:286)”.

> I learned you gotta do Wudhu, etc and recite certain things and do
>   certain things before going to bed. I haven't yet completely learned
>   how to do each prayer, I'm still trying to write everything down!
>   **Will Allah punish me for not doing them yet as I don't know them all?**

First of all, let me clarify that there are only five fard (obligatory) prayers; two rakats of fajr, four rakats of zuhr, four rakats of asr, three rakats of maghrib and four rakats of isa. The duas (supplication) recited before going to bed are not fard which means skipping them is halal (permissible).

If you intentionally miss any of the fard prayers mentioned above, you will be held accountable for that. You don't need to know how to pray to perform prayers. You may/should write down all the instructions of prayer and read from that while praying.

P.S. [This page](http://newmuslimguide.com/en/your-prayer/142) has detailed instructions regarding how to pray salah.

> **Will I have to make up prayers (even though I haven't even counted how many days I may have missed it) or is there a prayer I can do to
>   repent and ask for forgiveness?**

You don't have to make up the prayers you missed due to ignorance. But you should strive to do a lot of acts of worship and ask for Allah's forgiveness. Allah says in the Qur'an (interpretation of the meaning):

> [39:53] Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves
>   [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah . Indeed, Allah
>   forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the
>   Merciful."
>
> [3.133] And hasten to forgiveness from your Lord; and a Garden, the
>   extensiveness of which is (as) the heavens and the earth, it is
>   prepared for those who guard (against evil).

And Allah knows best.

---

P.S. Recommended websites for new Muslims:

- [Sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com) : The Hadith of the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him).
- [Quran.com](http://quran.com) : THE NOBLE QUR'AN.
- [Quora.com](http://quora.com) : QA website where you can ask questions regarding Islam or other topics.