# What is there to know about the awrah-ness of women's feet?

Tags: women, human-body, awrah

On my trip to Indonesia, I was surprised that it was normal for women to go around mosques with bare feet, even in front of non-mahram men.  I [heard](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32644/going-from-never-prayed-in-my-life-to-my-first-prayer#comment55602_32644) that Hanafi scholars don't consider feet part of the awrah, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_in_Indonesia) says "99% of Indonesian Muslims mainly follow the Shafi'i school of Sunni jurisprudence".  So now I'm confused...

**Question**: What is there to know about the awrah-ness of women's feet?

I'm seeking a succinct summary of which sects/schools have which opinions on the awrah-ness of women's feet.

Comment: I think the main thing that confuses you, is why people in Indonesian people, which according to the wikipedia page you cited is mainly follows Shafi'i sholars, follows Hanafi shcolars in relation to the understanding of awrah.

Comment: @SyakurRahman: Yes!  And welcome to Islam.SE.  (Love your country, by the way.  Inshallah, I'll go back many times.)

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Thank you very much. I just found this part of stackexchange, and it seems fun! I admit, that Islam here is more of a culture rather than a religion, hence sometimes differs from what have been said by authoritative Islamic sources, but it's getting better these days. So, please do always visit here.

Answer (score 2):

according to islamweb.net , The three schools say they are awrah. Abu-Hanifa said they are not. However , men should not look at them . Ibn-Nujaim (a high-level hanafi scholar died 970 AH) said there is no correlation between the feet being not awrah , and the permission to look at them, because the permission to look is to: what is not awrah , and when the worry of desire does not exist. "That's why it's forbidden to look at her face" , he added.

see https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/226801