# Is my prayer accepted if I read the duas on my own during prayer?

Tags: salat

I do know how to pray, all the moves and what to do even I do not know the duas during the Salah, I’ve been praying only when I’m with my friends and I also do not know the sayings, and the only things I know is Surah al-Fathiah. I now wanted to pray on my own.

Is my prayer accepted if I read the duas on my own whilst I’m doing my prayer?

Comment: It's unclear what "read" means here; see [Do you mean “read” (from a book) or “recite” (from memory) or “perform” (prayer)?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3333/do-you-mean-read-from-a-book-or-recite-from-memory-or-perform-prayer).  You might also be interested in [Going from “never prayed in my life” to my first prayer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32644/going-from-never-prayed-in-my-life-to-my-first-prayer)

Answer (score 0):

Bro Haris, Fateha is mandatory for every rikat, even if you only recite surah Fateha that will be valid. And Salah is obligatory in every situation so keep praying with whatever you know for now and start learning immediately.

> Verse (51:56) And I did not create the jinn and mankind except to
>   worship Me.

Our purpose of creation is only to worship Allah, so please manage some time every day to learn all these things, better to take help from your family members, if not then friends then to anyone who can help you.

Comment: Salam Brother Haris, Bismillah, Sura -al -Fatihah is mandatory for every rakkat, even if you only recite Surah-al-Fatihah that will be valid. And Salah is obligatory in every situation so keep praying with whatever you know for now and start learning immediately.


> Verse (51:56) And I did not create the jinn and mankind except to worship Me.

Our purpose of creation is only to worship Allah, so please manage some time every day to learn all these things, better to take help from your family members, if not then friends  Jazakallah .edit your answer this way Salam

Answer (score 0):

First, no human should be able to tell if your prayer will be accepted or not. It is only Allah to decide.
The question is if your prayer right or not.
To answer your question, you better memorize the Duaa in each step as Muhamad PBUH taught us. What you can do is to print them on a piece of paper, understand their meanings and use the paper during your prayer. At some stage you will memorize them and won't need the peice of paper anymore.

Answer (score 0):

my friend, in relation to your question, is it acceptable to only recite the prayers in your prayers? You must first learn the correct way to pray and do not be lazy in this task. It is very easy to learn by repeating it many times. If you love God, it is a sweet thing for you. We don't know whether God will accept it or not, and we should pray after praying that God will accept our prayer and treat the snake with his own kindness. For better teaching of prayer, search on the internet, they will teach you if you are Shia or Sunni. Search that way, God willing, may God grant you His mercy and grace